# What happens in an oauth flow when a User is already logged in?

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-oauth

I'm already logged into a gmail account. But when I go to a website that says I can use an identity provider, clicking on a use gmail as an identity, I get redirected to a website that wants me to logon again.

Is this what is supposed to happen? What is the flow for this? And what are the reasons this happens?